# How to exactly know what event will be triggered when and what data can be captured in observer?

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I am quite unsure of how to know which event will occur when. I cannot understand what arguments I should capture in observer unless I find exactly what I want in internet.

Comment: You can follow this article https://gordonlesti.com/create-a-list-of-dispatched-events-in-magento2/

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2, some observers will be dispatched in core code like this:

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch('catalog_product_collection_load_after', ['collection' => $this]);
```

As you see, you can get argument by call `$observer->getEvent()->getColelction();`

Also, some observers will not. In this situation, you have to use some IDE support debug to get what the event dispatch!.

Comment: How to do with IDE?

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: Sublime Text 3.

Comment: It will be better to develop and debug with phpStorm mate.

Comment: Can I get a free version of it?

Comment: Actually It is not free, but you can get some key active in some site that provide.